# OpenGL / GLSL line trails

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to draw a line, and then have a trail that fades behind it as it moves.
Think of the "Curves and Colors" screensaver from Windows 98. It's kind of a really simple-looking motion blur shader I guess?

I've been searching for various things for hours with no luck. Maybe there's some term for it that I don't know or function I need to use?

Can I do it with GLSL and save the previous points that the line was at, and then fade those out over time?
Or do I have to save the lines to 10 different frame buffers and then fade those out?

I'm not really sure where to start, sorry.

Comment: All that screen saver is doing is drawing the same curve multiple times just offset and slightly rotated it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need 1 extra frame buffer to draw to -- the steps required are to first render the previous framebuffer as a texture multiplied with a factor (say 0.9) and then draw a new line with maximum intensity; then swap buffers.

A simpler method is to redraw a set of lines with different intensities -- one of the lines will be redrawn with intensity of 0 (black), a new line as 1 (white, green, whatever) and everything else with an intensity inbetween.